# Logistc regression - changes in the deviance

Tags: statistics, logistic-regression

I'm reading about the logistic regression and i came across a phrase that i can't understand. The sentence is as follows (from the book: Introductory Statistics with R, Peter Dalgaard):

"Changes in the deviance caused by a model reduction will be approximately Chi-squared distributed with degrees of freedom equal to the change in the number of parameters"

Could someone explain this phrase to me? To calculate this change i use the Probability density function or the Cumulative distribution function?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I suspect the general intent is that the goodness of fit decreases as the number of parameters decreases, and the change in goodness of fit has a certain distribution. Look at the definition of deviance -- do they mean, perhaps, the negative log likelihood or something like that? Btw this question is more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for replying. With your answer I think I'm starting to understand what the phrase means, and I'm going to follow your advice and ask this in the community you indicated. thanks for your time.